# CPU for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, cpu

We want to buy a new server for SQL server,

We have around 10 DB, and heavy jobs every 10 minutes to process millions of records,

Also, we have around 20 end users,

We want to know what is the best CPU for this server,

and what is the advantage/disadvantage of option2 vs option1 (is the same cores)

and multi - CPU vs multi-core, option 1 vs option 3 with more clock speed, but 2 smaller CPU,

Option 1

Intel Platinum 8280 , 28C/56T, 2.70 GHz/ 4.00 GHz T,

Price **$20,564**

https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/servers-storage-and-networking/poweredge-r640-rack-server/spd/poweredge-r640/pe_r640_12232c_vi_vp?view=configurations&configurationid=ba0f44e1-7290-4300-aee3-936b7f24e1ae

Option 2

Intel Gold 6258R , 28C/56T, 2.70 GHz/ 4.00 GHz T,

Price **$13,704**

https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/servers-storage-and-networking/poweredge-r640-rack-server/spd/poweredge-r640/pe_r640_12232c_vi_vp?view=configurations&configurationid=7ad77f56-2569-4eda-b051-0aa1624d9d45

Option 3

2 X Intel Gold 6246R, 16C/32T, a total of 32C/64T 3.40 GHz/ 4.10 GHz T,

Price **$16,865**

https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/servers-storage-and-networking/poweredge-r640-rack-server/spd/poweredge-r640/pe_r640_12232c_vi_vp?view=configurations&configurationid=415b8bb1-c446-4836-aec4-16b1569eb915

This is the comparison of the CPU

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=199353,199350,192478

Thanks

Michael

Comment: This will likely be closed as a "shopping list question." You should look at Glenn Alan Berry's CPU recommendations which he publishes at least annually. The latest for Intel is https://glennsqlperformance.com/2020/05/21/recommended-intel-processors-for-sql-server/ . Just remember, the CPU is the cheap piece - you have to pay to license SQL Server for all those cores and that's FAR more expensive.

Comment: I don't see how this is a "shopping list" question. An expert in the area ought to be able to give a good answer. This seems like the sort of question DBAs might face quite often.

Comment: Is your workload currently CPU-bound? Will your workload be able to take advantage of parallelism? Why do you think that the processor choice is the principal criteria for the new server selection?

Comment: The DB jobs can run in parallelism

Answer (score 1):

Following your link option 1 (Intel Platinum 8280) & 2 (Intel Gold 6258R) are pretty much the same. Option 3 (Intel Gold 6246R) is the only one that looks somehow different:

[image]

Option 1 & 2 have the same:

- Number of cores
- Number of Threads
- Processor frequency
- Max Frequency
- Cache

...you only can decide to take Option 1 (**Intel Platinum 8280**) and pay 6.059$ more if you need 3 UPI links instead of the 2 that Option 2 provides, the  **Intel Gold 6258R**.

In the other hand Option 3, the **Intel Gold 6246R** looks cheaper but it has:

- nearly half of the cores
- nearly half of the Threads
- higher Processor Frequency
- higher Max frequency

**Overall the choice would be:**

Choose the `Intel Gold 6246R` if you need high processor frequency and you don't do so much parallel computation.

Choose the `Intel Gold 6258R` if you need to do parallel computation (for example if you have a lot of query computing from lots of clients)

Choose the `Intel Platinum 8280` if you need 3 UPI Links.

Comment: HI Francesco Mantovani, We need parallel and also higher Frequency, heavy jobs in the DB will split to parallel, Option 3 is **2 X** Intel Gold 6246R, 16C/32T, a total of **32C/64T** 3.40 GHz/ 4.10 GHz T,  the question is if option 3 will be faster the option 2,  Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, Option 3 is better because: Option 3 = 32C/64T while Option 2 = 28C/56T. Of course the parallelism is what most of DBA looks for and I will suggest you that way. If you are using SQL Server 2019 I also suggest you to put as much RAM as you can as 2019 makes a high use of RAM for caching the query plan. If you have tons of RAM your queries will run faster